# Rename the "formal" tag to "Formal Language"?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There's a [formal](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal) tag used in [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/33/are-formal-honorific-forms-mandatory-when-talking-about-himself) that would possibly be more clear if it were renamed to a noun such as "formal language" or "formality". Should we change it, create a synonym, or leave it be?

Comment: might 'speech' imply that we aren't also talking about writing?

Comment: @topomorto good point. How about just "Formality"? It seems (at least in my head) to make more sense to make the tag's name a noun instead of an adjective.

Comment: the noun 'register' relates (partly) to how formal language is - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics), but that would apply to questions asking about formal and informal language.

Comment: for formal language, how about *formal-language* ?

Comment: @topomorto that makes a lot of sense, I've edited the question to use that instead of "Formal Speech"

Answer (score 3):

## +1 for *formal-language*

Comparing with *formality* and *register*:

- ***formality*** sounds very technical, and isn't as immediately comprehensible as *formal-language*. *formality* also may refer to other things.
- ***register*** includes all levels of formality, and it should discuss about each register itself, no the topics within the register, e.g. it should talk about how formal registers compare with others, or how they function as registers, not how things should be done in the formal registers

About whether to make a synonym or just re-tag the question, I would favor re-tag. This should always be the preferred choice if you are confident the tag wouldn't appear again. Luckily with the current small size of this site re-tagging is very easy, and more importantly SE's tag autocomplete would redirect new would-be *formal* tags to *formal-language*, and hopefully this can serve to unify all future questions of this topic under this one tag, without the need to use synonyms.